# Session handling in PHP and Zend

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2, session-variables, session-cookies

I got a really strange problem in my PHP webapp.
If I log in, everything works fine for the duration of my session.
If I come in the next day, my webapp returns me to the Login page (as I expect).

The problem is that once I log in, parts of my site work and parts don't.  The parts that don't return strange error messages and then I'm logged out and need to log back in.  The strange thing is that some days some parts don't work and other days other parts don't work.  If I delete all cookie values I can see, that doesn't solve the problem.  The problem is only solved by deleting the entire cookie itself and then logging in again.

I've turned off garbage collection (because on Ubuntu there is supposedly a cron job which does it automatically even though I can't see it) but the issue was occurring before that.

So in terms of simplicity my intention is two-fold:
-  To add code to my Login page to delete the cookie entirely (assuming I can do that from PHP)
-  To move session storage from my webserver to my MySQL DB (because I'm in my dev environment but preparing to build my test environment which will be a cluster of webservers, not just one)

My questions are:
-  Is there any way to ensure session values die reliably and gracefully rather than lingering and wreaking havoc?
-  Is it possible to delete an entire cookie from PHP code, rather than just cookie values?

Many thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: What do you mean by "lingerng and wreaking havoc"? What were the strange error messages you were seeing?

Comment: Sometimes (like this morning) there is no issue.  Often after logging in and clicking the first page (any page) thereafter, I get returned to the login page.  Sometimes all pages work but one (which differs) which returns a different error each time.  Essentially the error messages imply that it cannot find data because it doesn't know my userid because I'm not logged on (even though I am and other pages work fine).

Answer (score 0):

After being a constant problem for a while, this issue has gone away. I've actually determined the cause and so I thought I'd post a quick update. Basically I had three sites I was accessing on my domain, my own webapp, a CMS Admin page and another admin tool. I've determined that the session cookies between my webapp and CMS admin were interfering with each other. If I use different browsers to access the different sites, the problem doesn't reoccur. It was driving me up the wall. Thanks to those who posted suggestions/responses. I appreciate it. I'll mark this as closed.